# Using Webpack when extending a browser-native class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am using Webpack with React and Typescript and I'm trying to create a wrapper class for WebSocket, a browser native class.

The class is in a file `webSocketConnection.ts` and looks something like this:

```
export default class WebSocketConnection extends WebSocket {
    constructor(url: string, protocols?: string | string[]) {
        super(url, protocols);
    }
}
```

A separate file imports and uses it

```
import WebSocketConnection from './webSocketConnection';

export function Connect() {
    return new WebSocketConnection("<<someUrl>>");
}
```

It builds fine, but then on running the site I get `NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined`.

From my understanding, this is a server side error due to node not finding the `WebSocket` object, even though it works fine on the client. This works perfectly fine when just using `new Websocket("<<someUrl>>")`.

My expectation is that this could be solved by excluding that specific file from being bundled, or from the server seeing it.

My `webpack.config.js` is

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const sharedConfig = () => ({
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
            alias: {
                ["~"]: path.resolve(__dirname, "ClientApp"),
            }
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    });

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.tsx' },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    oneOf: [
                        {
                            resourceQuery: /raw/,
                            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                        },
                        {
                            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' })
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'less-loader'])
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css'),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
            ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' },
                { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'ignore-loader' }
            ]
        },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.tsx' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

**UPDATE 2 36pm**
The result after transpiling is as so:

```
var WebSocketConnection = (function (_super) {
    __extends(WebSocketConnection, _super);
    function WebSocketConnection(url, protocols) {
        return _super.call(this, url, protocols) || this;
    }
    return WebSocketConnection;
}(WebSocket));
```

Comment: I would check the result of transpiling this first

Comment: I've added the result. Can see why WebSocket would blow up in node. Not sure how to change the original code to output something that wouldn't blow up.

Comment: Does calling it as `window.WebSocket` help?

Comment: Because of typescript, window doesn't work since it doesn't contain WebSocket, but it gives me an idea to try a few options. Thanks!

Comment: if you are running this code in node then of course node doesn't have nor window neither websocket, as far as I know

Comment: Right, those are browser native implementations. The code, however, is not meant to run in node, but in the browser, it's just transpiled using node. So I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to not transpile that specific file in node (leaving it out of the bundle, but still having it exist in the browser) or write it in such a way that it still works when run in node, but gives me the effect I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 6:42 PM:** After further testing, the original answer did build correctly but did not run correctly. Despite explicitly setting the prototype to WebSocket, it still called WebSocketMock during `super()`.

A second method did work, only to find you can't extend WebSocket at all in Chrome, because you'll always get the error `Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

In case somebody else needs to extend a browser-native class that *can* be extended, this is how it was successfully accomplished:

```
///Inside of file webSocketConnection.ts
export interface WebSocketConnection extends WebSocket {
    //Custom properties here
}

let classVar: any;

if (typeof(WebSocket) !== 'undefined') {
    classVar= class WebSocketConnection extends WebSocket {
        constructor(url: string, protocols?: string | string[]) {
            super(url, protocols);
        }
    }
}

export default function(url: string, protocols?: string | string[]): WebSocketConnection {
    return new classVar(url, protocols) as WebSocketConnection;
}
```

--

```
///Inside of a second file
import createWebSocket, { WebSocketConnection } from './webSocketConnection';

function DoSomething() {
    //Note no "new" keyword used, because this function isn't actually a constructor
    let socket: WebSocketConnection = createWebSocket("<<someUrl>>");
}
```

For completion's sake, the non-TypeScript solution would look something like this:

```
///Inside of file webSocketConnection.js
let classVar;

if (typeof(WebSocket) !== 'undefined') {
    classVar = class WebSocketConnection extends WebSocket {
        constructor(url, protocols) {
            super(url, protocols);
        }
    }
}

export default function(url, protocols) {
    return new classVar(url, protocols);
}
```

--

```
///Inside of a second file
import createWebSocket from './webSocketConnection';

function DoSomething() {
    //Note no "new" keyword used, because this function isn't actually a constructor
    let socket = createWebSocket("<<someUrl>>");
}
```

---

**Original Answer -- Did not work, but left here as it may provide insight to someone**

OP here, the solution that worked meant creating a mock class `WebSocketMock` that had all the same properties as `WebSocket`, but not implemented, and have `WebSocketConnection` extend `WebSocketMock`. Afterwards, I would update the prototype of `WebSocketConnection` to be `WebSocket`, if it existed. This `if` statement was true in the browser, but false in node.

TypeScript solution:

```
/* Mock class = WebSocketMock; new empty class that looks similar to original class
 * Original class = WebSocket; browser-only class we want to extend
 * New class = WebSocketConnection; class that extends original class
 */

/* Creating a blank interface, with the same name as the mock class,
 * that extends the original interface we're trying to mock
 * allows the mock class to have all the properties of the original class
 * without having to actually implement blank versions of them
 */
interface WebSocketMock extends WebSocket {
}

/* The mock class must have the same constructor as the original class
 * so that the new class can use super() with the right signature
 */
class WebSocketMock {
    constructor(url: string, protocols?: string | string[]) {
    }
}

// New class extends the mock class
export default class WebSocketConnection extends WebSocketMock {
    constructor(url: string, protocols?: string | string[]) {
        super(url, protocols);
    }

    //Other properties and code will be added here
}

/* Updates the prototype of the new class to use the original class
 * when the original class exists. Of course, if you try to use the new
 * class in an environment (read: browser) that doesn't have the original
 * class, everything would break, as it's just an empty "shim"
 */
if (typeof (WebSocket) !== 'undefined')
    Object.setPrototypeOf(WebSocketConnection, WebSocket);
```

Without typescript, it would likely look something like this (I don't have a TypeScript-free environment that uses Webpack for me to test with)

```
class WebSocketMock {
    constructor(url, protocols) {
    }
}

export default class WebSocketConnection extends WebSocketMock {
    constructor(url, protocols) {
        super(url, protocols);
    }

    //Other properties and code will be added here
}

if (typeof (WebSocket) !== 'undefined')
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(WebSocketConnection), WebSocket);
```